# Como realizar comandos "sudo" entre servidores?

Tags: r, linux, shiny-server

Antes de rodar um R script no servidor 'A' tenho restartar o shiny-server no servidor 'B'.

```
/bin/ssh cabala@***.***.***.*** 'sudo service shiny-server restart'
```

Gostaria de introduzir no R script no servidor 'A' um comando `system()` que restarte o shiny-server no servidor 'B'. Ainda teria o problema de enviar a senha do sudo neste comando.

Comment: Precisa ser automática a entrada da senha? Se sim, você pode olhar o argumento `-a` do `sudo (man sudo)`. Se você quer digitar a senha quando rodar o script isso pode ajudar : `system('sudo -kS service shiny-server restart', input = readline("Enter your password: "))`

Comment: Sim, é uma rotina interna e não teria problema de automatizar a entrada da senha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vá ao servidor A e faça a cópia da chave para o servidor B.
Se ainda não gerou SSH Key, você fazer seguindo os passos desse [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ssh-keys?topic=ssh-keys-generating-and-using-ssh-keys-for-remote-host-authentication&locale=pt-br)

1) Copiando a chave ssh do Servidor A para o Servidor B:

```
ssh-copy-id cabala@***.***.***.*** # IP ou DNS do Servidor B
```

2) Teste o ssh para saber se está logando sem senha:

```
ssh cabala@***.***.***.*** # IP ou DNS do Servidor B
```

3) Tenha certeza que o usuário tenha permissão para usar sudo rodando o comando que você quer:

```
sudo service shiny-server restart
```

Após esses passos você conseguirá rodar o comando remotamente sem necessidade de senha e conseguirá rodar a cron do jeito que mencionou.